# getting nhl standings with python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I wrote a function using python and selenium to use BeautifulSoup on a url:

```
def get_soup(url):
    d = webdriver.Chrome()
    d.get(url)
    result = d.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
    return soup
```

I'm trying to scrape the current NHL standings from this url: https://www.nhl.com/standings/league

I am running into 2 issues that I don't know how to get around:

1) If you follow this url, it takes you to the "league" tab, but the scraping doesn't distinguish between this tab and the others.

2) The three elements in the "National Hockey League" column (ranking, logo, name) are three separate things, but they are in a single column.

I'd like to pull this data into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the source code of the website, and found the internal NHL API. You can scrape the rankings [here](https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/standings). The only thing that this listing doesn't have is a logo, but it has the other things you're looking for. Just note that since this doesn't appear to be public, the URL can change at any time.